# Netlogo print values and text in the same line

Tags: printing, netlogo

I know how to print a variable and a text but I want to make it in the same line, If i Use:

```
print "text" MYVARIABLE
```

I got an exception

> Expected command

So the question is: there is a way to print text and variable on the same line?
Thank you

Comment: Luke's answer is good, but I tend to do `type "text" print MYVARIABLE` when I want to do something like this.There are four different print to screen commands - with and without line throw, and with and without the agent identifier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! The `word` primitive is what you are after- see [the dictionary definition here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#word).

In brief, you can follow the syntax:

```
print word "Count turtles: " count turtles
```

Or

```
print ( word "There are " count turtles " turtles right now" )
```